# Lookup and if no match in table 1, lookup table 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having trouble creating a formula to look up a result from one table if the correct match is not found in another table.

I want the user to input this information:
Is this a production plant? Yes/No
zip code: XXXXX
I am looking for results to be returned from table 1 or 2 depending on the inputs.

A - If the answer is yes and the zip code is in table 2, then return a result from the appropriate cell in table 2.

B - If the answer is yes and the zip code is not in table 2, then return a result from the appropriate cell in table 1.

C - If the answer is no, then return a result from the appropriate cell in table 1.

With this formula:

=IF(H1="no",(VLOOKUP(H2,G6:I8,3,TRUE)),IF(H1="yes",(VLOOKUP(H2,F12:I14,3,TRUE))))

I can resolve scenario A and C, but obviously not B.  I've tried variations of the above formula using: and, vlookup, match, iferror, isna. These either have not worked or only return results for some of the scenario.

IF I use this:
=IF(AND(H1="yes",H2<>(F12:F14)),VLOOKUP(H2,G6:I8,3),"error")))

I can get B resolved.  However, if I combine it with the above code, it no longer resolves B, just A & C:

=IF(H1="no",(VLOOKUP(H2,G6:I8,3,TRUE)),IF(H1="yes",(VLOOKUP(H2,F12:I14,3,TRUE)),IF(AND(H1="yes",H2<>(F12:F14)),VLOOKUP(H2,G6:I8,3),"error")))

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the suggestions!

I've tried them and I'm not quite there.  I think I need to explain this better.

I've attached a screenshot (I can't embed them, yet):

[screenshot of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW2Gt.png)

I'm able to get the 1st and 3rd answers correctly (as shown in the image), however the 2nd does not resolve correctly.

This formula gives me those results:

```
=IF(C1="no",(VLOOKUP(C2,B6:D8,3,TRUE)),IF(C1="yes",VLOOKUP(C2,A12:D14,3,TRUE)),IF(AND(C1="yes",C2<>(A12:A14)),VLOOKUP(C2,B6:D8,3),"error")))
```

Thanks everyone for your input, this is finally resolved!

Comment: `H2<>(F12:F14)` this is not going to work.

Comment: When you set the last criteria in the VLOOKUP to TRUE, you will always return an answer, you probably want that to be set to FALSE. Then I think  you could use the IFNA formula. This should replace the inner IF of your formula.

Comment: @ Alex M - I agree, just trying to convey the intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Multistage lookup solves the issue:*

**Situation 1:**

- Yes & Zip Code found in Table 1.

[image]

---

**Situation 2:**

- Yes & Zip Code found in Table 2.

[image]

---

**Situation 3:**

- No & Zip Code found in Table 2.

[image]

**N.B.**

- *If `No & Zip code not found in Table 2` then formula returns `Blank`*
- *If `Yes or No & Zip code not found in either tables` then also the formula returns `Blank.`*
- `Blank` can be replaced with suitable Text also.

*Formula in Cell `L7`:*

```
=IFERROR(IF($I$7="Yes",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J$7,$I$3:$J$5,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J$7,$I$10:$J$12,2,0),VLOOKUP($J$7,$I$10:$J$12,2,0))),VLOOKUP($J$7,$I$10:$J$12,2,0)),"")
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks for your input! it works great in the test set up you've created.  I've modified it for the table in my example and it still isn't getting the correct result except when the zip code matches table 2.  I think this is because table 1 has a range of zip codes, not single zip codes.

Comment: Glad to help you @marke626,, keep asking ☺, I've used exactly what the screen shot does have table structure,, only values been modified,, you may flip table with Vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

**Formula**

```
=IF(OR(Production_Plant="No", ISNA(VLOOKUP(ZIP_Code, Table2, 2, 0))),
    VLOOKUP(ZIP_Code,Table1,2,0), VLOOKUP(ZIP_Code,Table2,2,0))
```

Where

- `Production_Plant` Holds "Yes" or "No"
- `ZIP_Code` Holds the ZIP code to be looked up
- `Table1` and `Table2` are the two tables

**How it works**

We have a single `IF()` statement. We look in `Table1` if *either*

1. `Production_Plant` is "No"
2. The ZIP Code cannot be found in `Table2`. This is accomplished with the `ISNA()` function which @gns100 referred to.

Otherwise, it looks in `Table2`

**Screenshot**

[image: VLOOKUP in Two Tables]

I used [FormulaChop](https://formulachop.com) to generate this formula and screenshot. (Full disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop)